# Strange behavior: reload necessary to close an account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

For deactivating an account I have a method similar to this:

```
def closing         # Controller method
  @user = current_user
  relationships = @user.relationships
  relationships.each { |relationship| relationship.destroy }
  log_out
end

def log_out         # In sessions helper
  forget(current_user)
  session.delete(:user_id)
  @current_user = nil
end

def forget(user)    # In sessions helper
  debugger
  user.forget       # If I change this to user.reload.forget the error below is gone
  cookies.delete(:user_id)
  cookies.delete(:api_token)
end

def forget          # In User table
  update_attributes(remember_digest: nil, email_digest: nil)
end
```

However, closing an account produces an error message for the line `user.forget`:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Relationship with
>   'id'=129095216 [WHERE "relationships"."user_id" = ?]

See the location of `debugger` in the code above. I used the debugger to look at the values for `user`: the field `default_relationship_id` still has the value `129095216`. If I enter `user.reload` then the value of `default_relationship_id` is indeed `nil`. And indeed, rewriting that line in the sessions helper to `user.reload.forget` and everything works.

However, reloading shouldn't be necessary. In fact in the past it used to work, I have been changing quite some code since but don't understand the behavior. There must be something wrong because reloading shouldn't be necessary. What to do? What is causing this behavior?

---

More on the association (no changes were made to this code from the time the above error wasn't there):

User model:

```
has_many   :relationships, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
has_many   :organizations, through: :relationships, inverse_of: :users
belongs_to :default_relationship, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :default_relationship_id, inverse_of: :default_for_user
has_one    :default_organization, through: :default_relationship, source: :organization
```

Relationship model:

```
belongs_to :user,         :inverse_of => :relationships
belongs_to :organization, :inverse_of => :relationships
has_one    :default_for_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :default_relationship_id, inverse_of: :default_relationship, dependent: :nullify
```

Comment: Do you load relationships with the user model? Why do you remove relationships through `relationships.each { |relationship| relationship.destroy }` instead of `@user.relationships.destroy_all` (they do exactly the same!)

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming; the only reason was I didn't know of `destroy_all` its existence. So I've now replaced the current code as suggested. The error persisted though (all other tests still passed). Regarding your first question: I assume since the association is there, it automatically loads with the user model...?

Comment: Try `current_user.relationships.destroy_all` in controller

Comment: I'm now using `@user.relationships.destroy_all if @user.relationships.any?`. (also tried it without the `if` part but that made no difference for the error) I'm using `@user` because in the code I have a before_action that defines `@user`, which is not necessarily equal to `current_user`. Just changed the syntax a bit in my OP to make my post shorter.

Comment: 1. There is no reason to do `if @user.relationships.any?` because if there are none, none will be removed. 2. `current_user` is a helper I guess so it's available in all other helpers, no need to pass it around! 3. If you assign `@user = current_user` then it's nothing else than current_user for sure. If you're closing other user than current then I don't understand why you log them out. 4. Please add any scopes and callbacks you have on user model to the question 5. And most important - seems you try to implement login yourself, it's a very bad idea. Use devise gem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to remove the cookies and/or values stored in session is a flawed approach. Instead you should be using [`reset_session`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures) - it invalidates the current session identifier and issues a new one.

```
def log_out         # In sessions helper
  reset_session
  @current_user = nil
end
```

So that even if the user still has a cookie pointing to their previous session Rails will not load the session.

## In memory vs in database.

```
@user = current_user
relationships = @user.relationships
relationships.each { |relationship| relationship.destroy }
```

Note that in this code you are storing an `User` object in `@user` and a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object in `relationships` - these are both stored in the servers memory. When you iterate through `relationships` and destroy each you are not updating the values stored in memory in `@user`. Thats why `.reload` is needed - it refreshes the stale `@user` object with the representation from the database.

Instead you should use `destroy_all` as pointed out as it produces a more effective database query and uses less memory than iterating through each item.

```
def closing         # Controller method
  @user = current_user
  @user.relationships.destroy_all
  @user = @user.reload
end
```

Comment: As a side comment - its fine to try to do an authentication solution yourself as an experiment when learning but if you intend to actually use the app on the wild webs you should instead use a tried and true authentication solution like Devise or at least Warden. Doing authentication right is one of the hardest things to get right as a programmer and most hacks are due to home rolled auth solutions.

Comment: Great, thanks max for the clear explanation. The thing is though that after replacing it with `destroy_all`, the same error is still there.

Comment: Ah, I was a bit ensure if `.destroy_all` updates the `User` object - this confirms that it does not. It might be prudent in this case to use `.reload` to make sure the object in memory is synced with its database representation.